# Using find and grep in linux command line to search for files with a specific user and text content?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to find a file that belongs to a specific user, that also contains a specific string of text.
For example, I want to find a file that belongs to the root user, and contains the text "hello there".

I know I can search for text in files using grep for example:

```
grep -irl "hello there" /directory1
```

And, I know I can search for files owned by a user with specific extensions:

```
find -user root -name "*.txt"
```

Is there a way that I can combine these two commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `grep` once with all of the matching files:

```
find -user root -name "*.txt" -exec grep -il "hello there" {} +
```

Or call `grep -q` once for each file and `-print` the files that match.

```
find -user root -name "*.txt" -exec grep -iq "hello there" {} \; -print
```

(`-exec` can be used as a test just like `-user` or `-name`. If the command succeeds, the `-exec` test passes and `-print` is invoked.)